# Shnayim Ve'arba'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred forty-two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lot died at 142 according to [ספר הישר, פ׳ חיי שרה](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40009&st=&pgnum=88&hilite=).

Answer (score 1):

[Tehillim 142](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26e2.htm) is one of the Psalms we [traditionally](http://www.aish.com/sp/pr/48960976.html) [recite](http://www.artscroll.com/itehillim.html) in times of trouble.